# Post and Pre increment

Tags: c++, post-increment, pre-increment

The output of the following code

```
int k=10;
int g=5;
int s=g+k++;
cout<<s;
```

is 15

but the output of the following code

```
int k = 10;
int s= ++k + k++;
cout << s;
```

is coming as 23.
What is the correct explanation?
this was doubt number #1

doubt number #2 is

```
int m = 10;
int n = 10;
int a = 1 + (++m) + (++(++m))++;
int b = (++n) + (++(++n))++;
```

how is the value of both a and b the same which is 27

Comment: I believe the answer is that you're modifying `k` twice without an intervening sequence point, so the code has undefined behaviour. But this isn't the right site to ask technical C++ questions.

Comment: which site is better then

Comment: This kind of question gets asked pretty often. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior) a dupe.

Comment: There is no [tag:linear-programming] here, and practically everything in computer programming involves [tag:logic]. Don't tag indiscriminately.